# Issue With HTML/CSS Margins With Images

Tags: html, css, image, margin

I'm trying to get the margin of an image in HTML/CSS to be 0px but when I use

```
body {
margin: 0px;
}
```

it affects the entire body (image and text). That's expected. So I thought, well I'll just use a class. I tried this:

CSS:

```
.class-name {
margin: 0px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<img class="class-name" src="path/to/file.png">
```

Now it just simply ignores the fact that I have a margin... Any fixes? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Doomenik that class name was just an example, I'm actually using my own class name haha! Also, what do you mean by a working example?

Comment: @Doomenik Do not suggest third party sites like plunkr or jsfiddle. He is required to post his markup here. Anywhere else will get this question closed.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. [mcve]

Comment: @Doomenik Third party sites can produce dead links or changed code making the question worthless. You can use them to compliment what you are trying to show but [mcve].  If it doesn't get closed, they're either lucky or we haven't gotten to it yet. There are just under 10K questions up for closing evaluation right now.

Comment: @Doomenik aha that works! thanks! also sorry for the late reply :P

Comment: Alrighty thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case setting margin:0px; on your image doesn't help you at all. The reason why your image has a margin in the first case is because the body element has a default margin of (as far as I know) 8px.

To remove your margin you therefore have to either remove the margin of your body like this:

```
body {
margin:0px;
(or margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px etc)
}
```

Or to set the margin of your image to a negative value.

```
.class-name {
margin: -8px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but the negative margin seems to be doing the trick! Thanks so much! :)